# Strange encoding of non-latin characters in Microsoft Word metadata embedded in a PDF file

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, encoding, metadata

I have a PDF file created from a Microsoft Word document that contains a block:

```
20 0 obj
<<
/Author ( 52 &>;AB>9)
/Producer (Microsoft: Print To PDF)
/Title (Microsoft Word - ^T>:C<5=B1)
>>
endobj
```

I suppose this is Microsoft Word metadata. This is not a part of the **info** dictionary that can be displayed with `pdfinfo` or any PDF-reader. I wonder how to decode these fields. I assume that these are Cyrillic letters.

**Update:** I could find a couple of word documents on the web with the same text in the Title field, so this might be just a signature of some pirated version of Microsoft Office.

Comment: "signature of some pirated version of Microsoft Office" seems to be a non-sequitur. Author and title are from *user's* template.

Comment: If you've seen the same sequence "Microsoft Word - ^T>:C<5=B1" on the web and you know the encoding is Cyrillic, the chances are the "^T>:C<5=B1" part is the equivalent of "Document1", "Document2" etc, i.e. the name of an unsaved document. If you know what that is in the likely local language maybe that will help with the encoding part. OTOH If it's encoded in 8 bytes, maybe only 4 chars, which seems a little short if it's a variation on, say, Russian "документ"

Comment: Or perhaps the equivalent of another standard document name such as "Letter1", "Email1", etc.

Comment: @jonsson yes this makes sence. I think this is the answer.

Comment: Looks like the highest bit got cut off, so that the letters from some 8-bit encoding got replaced with 7-bit ASCII characters.